# How to make website comptible with iOS and mouse over

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, compatibility, mouseover

Currently, my site is programmed with  "hover mouse over" indicating the names of the boxes (when your mouse goes on them), which works for Android and general Computers, but is not compatible with iOS.

Therefore if using an iPad or iPhone it requires the user to click the box twice (instead of once) because the hover mouse over isn't compatible.

How do I remove the hover mouse over for iOS applications only? Can you use "if statements" for this? or conditions?

Comment: I guess you should go further than just *disable* the hover mouse event. This SO thread may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956315/mouse-events-and-touch-events

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 feasible ways of doing this:

1. On the server side, use a technology such as WURFL to detect whether the end user is on iOS, and serve a different stylesheet.
2. On the client side, check the user agent string for ip(ad|hone|od) and patch the affected elements accordingly.